# How do I prevent ZeroMQ server accepting more than one connection?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a ZeroMQ (PAIR) server but if more than one client connects to it the server crashes with the message:

```
Assertion failed: !inpipe && !outpipe (pair.cpp:49)
```

How do I prevent this? My server code uses txzmq:

```
from txzmq import ZmqEndpoint, ZmqFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, task
from txzmq.connection import ZmqConnection
from zmq import constants

class PairConnection(ZmqConnection):

    socketType = constants.PAIR

    # Send a message to the drone
    def messageSend(self, message):
        print "Sending:", message
        self.send(message)

    # Receive a message from the drone.
    def messageReceived(self, message):      
        print message

factory_zmq = ZmqFactory()
factory_zmq.protocol = PairConnection(factory_zmq, ZmqEndpoint("bind", "tcp://*:5500")) 
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Doc specifically state 'The exclusive pair pattern is used to connect a peer to precisely one other peer.'. So I'm not sure what answer you are looking for. It also states 'This pattern is used for inter-thread communication across the inproc transport.' so by using it over TCP you are almost asking for trouble.